# text game if check1 and check2 and check3 statment

Tags: python, python-3.x

So this is the beginning of a simple text game im working on.
When I run the program it will run through them multiple times before it can get to done. Not just one for each like I want. But I still want it to pick them at random, so I'm not sure if there is a better way to do this? Could someone tell me what I did wrong?

```
import random
from collections import defaultdict

Blist = ["hash browns", "eggs", "cheese", "sausage"]
Dictionary = {"a":1,"b":1,"c":1,"d":1}
Tup = (1,2,3,4,5)
check1 = False
check2 = False
check3 = False

def question():
    answer = ((Blist), (Dictionary), (Tup))
    new = (random.choice(answer)) 
    print(new)
    print("which is this?")
    print("a List, Dictionary, or Tuple?")
    x = str(input('what is it?\n'))
    if check1 == True and check2 == True and check3 == True:
        multiL()
    else:
        if x == 'list' and new == Blist:
            global check1
            check1 = True
            print("that is correct, this is a list")
            question()
        if x == 'dictionary' and new == Dictionary:
            global check2
            check2 = True
            print("that is correct, this is a dictonary")
            question()
        if x == 'tuple' and new == Tup:
            global check3
            check3 = True
            print("that is correct, this is a tuple")
            question()
        if x == 're':
            multiL()
        else:
            print("that is not one of the choices, try again?\n")
            question()

def multiL():
    print("done")

question()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move your first line within your function outside of the function. For now, make it a list:

```
awnser = [(Blist), (Dictionary), (Tup)]

def question():
...
```

Then choose one of them at random within the function:

```
def question():
    newawn = (random.choice(awnser))
```

When one is chosen, you can now delete the appropriate selection from the list to avoid repetition:

```
if x == 'list' and newawn == Blist:
       global check1
       check1 = True
       print("that is correct, this is a list")
       awnser.remove(Blist)
       question()
```

You can use `awnser.remove()` to remove specific items from a list, such as in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the part

```
awnser = ((Blist), (Dictionary), (Tup))
```

outside the *question* function.

Then in the if where you check if it is the correct answer, remove the possibility from awnser fx:

```
        if x == 'list' and newawn == Blist:
           global check1
           check1 = True
           print("that is correct, this is a list")
           awnser = ((Dictionary), (Tup)) #New line, now with tuple.
           question()
```

When the tuple is empty, all 3 possibilities have been done. You can fx end with.

```
Try:
   newawn = (random.choice(awnser))
Except IndexError:
   print("done")
   return
```

P.S. It is spelled answer.

Comment: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'remove' i keep getting this error

Comment: It is my bad on the tupple, I didn't read your code correct. For the remove to work anwser has to be a list. I have edited the code in the post to be a tupple.

Comment: P.S It's spelled tuple :)

Comment: that worked! but now i have the issue of the random not being able to pick a choice since none exist so ill have to delete that?

Comment: i got it to work i just had to move this part down                              newawn = (random.choice(awnser)) 
    print(newawn)
    print("which is this?")
    print("a List, Dictionary, or Tuple?")
    x = str(input('what is it?\n'))

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by putting the types in a list and removing each one when it is correctly identified. The logic as a while can be simplified by using a loop and not having `question()` call itself recursively. You also don't need those global `check#` variables because you can just see there is any left in the list of types—if not, it means each has been correctly identified.

```
import random

Blist = ["hash browns", "eggs", "cheese", "sausage"]
Dictionary = {"a": 1, "b": 1, "c": 1, "d": 1}
Tup = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

def question():
    choices = [Blist, Dictionary, Tup]

    while choices:  # any left?
        choice = random.choice(choices)  # pick a remaining one
        print() 
        print(choice)
        correct_answer = False
        answer = input('what is this?\na List, Dictionary, or Tuple?\n')
        answer = answer.lower()
        if answer == 'list' and choice == Blist:
            print("that is correct, this is a list")
            correct_answer = True
        elif answer == 'dictionary' and choice == Dictionary:
            print("that is correct, this is a dictonary")
            correct_answer = True
        elif answer == 'tuple' and choice == Tup:
            print("that is correct, this is a tuple")
            correct_answer = True
        elif answer == 're':
            break
        else:
            print("that is not one of the choices, try again?\n")
        if correct_answer:
            choices.remove(choice)  # remove it from list of choices

    multiL()

def multiL():
    print("done")

question()
```